# Thread - synchronizing and sleeping thread refuses to wake up (LINUX)

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, sleep

I'm developing an application For OpenSUSE 12.1.

This application has a main thread and other two threads running instances of the same functions.  I'm trying to use `pthread_barrier` to synchronize all threads but I'm having some problems:

1. When I put the derived threads to sleep, they will never wake up for some reason.
2. (in the case when I remove the sleep from the other threads, throwing CPU usage to the sky) In some point all the threads reach `pthread_barrier_wait()` but none of them continues execution after that.

Here's some pseudo code trying to illustrate what I'm doing.

```
pthread_barrier_t barrier;
int main(void)
{
    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL , 3);
    pthread_create(&thread_id1, NULL,&thread_func, (void*) &params1);
    pthread_create(&thread_id2v, NULL,&thread_func, (void*) &params2);

    while(1)
    {
        doSomeWork();
        nanosleep(&t1, &t2);

        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

        doSomeMoreWork();
   }
}

void *thread_func(void *params)
{
    init_thread(params);

    while(1)
    {
        nanosleep(&t1, &t2);
        doAnotherWork();

        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a small example that can be compiled, or post the real relevant code. The pseudo-code might not have the error/bug your real code has.

Comment: Have you set the t1 variable properly?

Comment: The real code is too big. I posted only this pseudo code because I might have made a conceptual error. I'm really new at linux and multithread programing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has to do with the barrier as you've presented it in the pseudocode.  I'm making an assumption that your glibc is approximately the same as my machine.  I compiled roughly your pseudo-code and it's running like I expect: the threads do some work, the main thread does some work, they all reach the barrier and then loop.

Can you comment more about any other synchronization methods or what the work functions are?

This is the the example program I'm using:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct timespec req = {1,0}; //{.tv_sec = 1, .tv_nsec = 0};
struct timespec rem = {0,0}; //{.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 0};

pthread_barrier_t barrier;

void *thread_func(void *params) {
   long int name;
   name = (long int)params;
   while(1) {
      printf("This is thread %ld\n", name);
      nanosleep(&req, &rem);

      pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

      printf("More work from %ld\n", name);
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   pthread_t th1, th2;

   pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL , 3);
   pthread_create(&th1, NULL, &thread_func, (void*)1);
   pthread_create(&th2, NULL, &thread_func, (void*)2);

   while(1) {
      nanosleep(&req, &rem);
      printf("This is the parent\n\n");

      pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well. I'm using a mutex only to make sure I'm protecting some data, but this behavior does not change if I remove it. The work is really big. Involves SHM, some audio processing, some audio verification, but as far as i can debug it, all that doesn't matter. All I observe is that the threads get stuck in the sleep, except for the main. Even if I remove the barriers, the main thread keeps running for ever, and the other two threads will never wake up.

Comment: Maybe I could send you some of the source files, but maybe this would make thing more confusing.

Comment: I've found that dropping into a large code base usually just results in more confusion.  If the code is really so big, maybe it would be useful to break it into separate piece that you can independently test.  Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use condition variables in order to synchronize threads.
Here some website about how to do it i hope it helps.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html